# Article link detail not fetching on google plus even after using structure data

Tags: html, twitter, google-plus, metadata

I am trying to build a article section on the website selfishtravel.com. But the google plus/twitter is not able to render the details of the link when it is added to post.

But it works fine on facebook. 
the link of sample of article: http://selfishtravel.com/article/7/5_must_things_to_do_in_Jaipur

Blog: selfishtravel.com/blog

Answer (score 0):

The response headers for the site are incomplete.

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Date: Mon, 25 Sep 2017 15:49:34 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

At a minimum you should also be returning a `Content-Type` header so that bots like Google+ and Twitter know how to parse the response.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```